# Tabbed actionbar interface to fit screen, setMaxWidth doesn't scale to screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

## The goal:

I want to have a tabbed interface where all tabs are visible at all times.

## The problem:

I cannot split the screen-width between the created tabs so that they don't overflow (see second screen-shot). Based on this ([Change tab width in ActionBar.Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039817/change-tab-width-in-actionbar-tab)) SO-question and discussion, I used the solution proposed there as a basis. The function "setMaxWidth()" can be used to limit a Views width. By limiting each tab to a portion of the screenWidth they should all fit.

```
setMaxWidth(screenWidth*tabTextSize[i]/tabTextSizeSum);
```

But to accomplish this I need to get to the Views of all the tabs. I tried to do this by using the `setCustomview(layoutResId)` for each tab and then reaching them through `getCustomView()`. But the result (as can be seen in Screenshot 1) leads to the tabs text being literary "false".

So, is there a way to scale the tabs to fit on the screen without overflowing?

## Screenshots:

[image: Screenshot1]

It's hard to see, but there are 6 tabs, taking up about 2/3 of the actionbar-area, each with the text "false" in it.

[image: Screenshot2]

If the rows where the tabs have a customView set and the last for-loop are removed, the tabs looks good except from not fitting the screen.

## The code:

### MainActivity.java

```
package com.example;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // Declare Tab Variable
    ActionBar.Tab TabTool, TabSchedule, TabMessage, TabTNT, TabAlarm, TabOverview;
    Fragment fragmentTool =     new FragmentTabToolChange();
    Fragment fragmentSchedule = new FragmentTabSchedule();
    Fragment fragmentMessage =  new FragmentTabMessage();
    Fragment fragmentTNT=       new FragmentTabTNT();
    Fragment fragmentAlarm =    new FragmentTabAlarm();
    Fragment fragmentOverview = new FragmentTabOverview();

    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    int screenWidth;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        screenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        // Hide Actionbar Icon
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

        // Hide Actionbar Title
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);


        // Set Tab Icon and Titles
        TabTool = actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.toolText);
        TabSchedule = actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.scheduleText);
        TabMessage = actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.messageText);
        TabTNT = actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.tntText);
        TabAlarm = actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.alarmText);
        TabOverview = actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.overviewText);

        // Set Tab Listeners
        TabTool.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentTool));
        TabSchedule.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentSchedule));
        TabMessage.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentMessage));
        TabTNT.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentTNT));
        TabAlarm.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentAlarm));
        TabOverview.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentOverview));

        View toolView = findViewById(R.id.toolTextView);

        TabTool.setCustomView(toolView);
        TabSchedule.setCustomView(findViewById(R.id.scheduleTextView));
        TabMessage.setCustomView(findViewById(R.id.messageTextView));
        TabTNT.setCustomView(findViewById(R.id.tntTextView));
        TabAlarm.setCustomView(findViewById(R.id.alarmTextView));
        TabOverview.setCustomView(findViewById(R.id.overViewTextView));

        // Add tabs to actionbar
        actionBar.addTab(TabTool);
        actionBar.addTab(TabSchedule);
        actionBar.addTab(TabMessage);
        actionBar.addTab(TabTNT);
        actionBar.addTab(TabAlarm);
        actionBar.addTab(TabOverview);

        // Scale tab widths to fit window
        View tabView = actionBar.getTabAt(0).getCustomView();


        final int tabSize = actionBar.getTabCount();
        final int[] tabTextSize = new int[tabSize];

        int tabTextSizeSum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < tabSize; i++)
        {
            tabTextSize[i] = actionBar.getTabAt(i).getText().length();
            tabTextSizeSum += tabTextSize[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < tabSize; i++)
        {
            TextView tab = (TextView) actionBar.getTabAt(i).getCustomView();

            tab.setMaxWidth(screenWidth*tabTextSize[i]/tabTextSizeSum);
        }

        // Create Actionbar Tabs
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    }
}
```

### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="71dp"
        android:text="@+id/string.toolText" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scheduleTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="71dp"
        android:text="@+id/string.scheduleText" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messageTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="71dp"
        android:text="@+id/string.messageText"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tntTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="71dp"
        android:text="@+id/string.tntText" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/alarmTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="71dp"
        android:text="@+id/string.alarmText" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/overViewTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="71dp"
        android:text="@+id/string.overviewText" />

</FrameLayout>
```

## Version-data:

AndroidStudio version: 1.5.1

Android SDK-version: 19

buildToolsVersion 23.0.1