# ActionBar tabs set dynamic width according to screen width

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-tabs

I have 5 tabs in all. This is how I am adding them :

```
for (int i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {

                if (i == 0) {
                    actionBar.addTab(
                            actionBar.newTab()
                                    .setText(null)
                                    .setIcon(R.drawable.activity)
                                    .setTabListener(this));
                } else if (i == 1) {
                    actionBar.addTab(
                            actionBar.newTab()
                                    .setText(null)
                                    .setIcon(R.drawable.group)
                                    .setTabListener(this));
                } else if (i == 2) {
                    actionBar.addTab(
                            actionBar.newTab()
                                    .setText(null)
                                    .setIcon(R.drawable.message)
                                    .setTabListener(this));
                } else if(i == 3){
                    actionBar.addTab(
                            actionBar.newTab()
                                    .setText(null)
                                    .setIcon(R.drawable.notification)
                                    .setTabListener(this));
                }
                else
                {
                    actionBar.addTab(
                            actionBar.newTab()
                                    .setText(null)
                                    .setIcon(R.drawable.hamburger)
                                    .setTabListener(this));
                }
```

I tried [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590869/android-actionbar-set-width-to-the-tabs) solution but this sets the width of the tab icon and not the tab itself.

Following are the styles I have applied :

**App theme** :

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/actionBarTabBarStyle</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>  

 <style name="actionBarTabBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">1dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">1dp</item>
        <item name="android:minWidth">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:maxWidth">15dp</item>
        <item name="android:showDividers">none</item>
    </style>
```

I also tried using **customView** for the tab but it didn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabItemLayout"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewTab" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The tabs are too wide and the `tabBar` is sliding. How can I make the tabs take dynamic width as per the screen width without the sliding effect. i.e. all tabs should fit in the screen width and should be of equal width.

[image]

There are 4 tabs visible here. The **tabBar** is scrollable so the fifth tab appears on scrolling which I don't want.

Comment: There's about 5 different SO threads out there with different solutions. Making the tabs fit the screen (fixed width), is a major hack job. This page http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html talks about it, but has no solution. So it can be done. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16887902/last-tab-in-action-bar-is-cropped-goes-off-screen It's a good start, but be prepared to hack together 2-3 solutions to make this work smoothly.

Comment: Have you tried custom view for `ActionBar`?

Comment: @Xcihnegn : Yes I have. That changes the width of tab icons but not the tab.

Comment: You can refer to my answer for the post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28881599/how-to-change-viewpager-tab-colour-dynamically/28883927#28883927), and you can find out how `To remove possible gap around tab caused by custom view`

Comment: @Xcihnegn : If I am not wrong, I have applied this. Please check the above code.

Comment: Ok, how about your `TextView` layout?

Comment: @Xcihnegn : I just have the tab icon. There is no text to be displayed.

Comment: I means your layout for tab

Comment: Can you put a screenshot about your issue

Comment: @Nitish, I just made one solution, and I tested it, looks work. You can try it and we can improve it if problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Tab` view width is based on content/yourImage size, so to make tab view width smaller, we have to control the content/Image size. You can do this by putting `ImageView` inside `FrameLayout`, for example your `customView` can be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/tabItemLayout"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <FrameLayout
      android:layout_width="48dp"
      android:layout_height="48dp"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      >

    <ImageView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:adjustViewBounds="true"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:id="@+id/imageViewTab" />

   </FrameLayout> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

and custom style for tab:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">

             ... ...
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle</item>

</style>

<style name="ActionBarTabStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Base.ActionBar.TabView">
   <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dp</item>
   <item name="android:paddingRight">0dp</item>
   <item name="android:paddingTop">0dp</item>
   <item name="android:paddingBottom">0dp</item>
</style>
```

[SCREENSHOT]

For `FrameLayout` size with `24dp`:
[image: For <code>FrameLayout</code> size with <code>24dp</code>]

For `FrameLayout` size with `40dp`
[image: For <code>FrameLayout</code> size with <code>40dp</code>]

Comment: Still the same. android:layout_width="48dp"
      android:layout_height="48dp" will work for only one particular device screen size

Comment: which resolution device it works? mdpi, hdpi, or xhdpi?

Comment: I don't know that. I am saying, giving a constant value won't work for all devices. And I changed my customView to this, but it is still the same

Comment: I tested it, I even can fit 7 tabs just by making your image container to the suitable size

Comment: Do I need to do something in the code as well ? I am using setCustomView instead of setIcon now.

Comment: Could you give the complete set of changes you made if you are saying that you were able to fit 7 tabs.

Comment: Ok put custom style to answer. When use `24dp` for `FrameLayout`, I can fit 6 tabs, maybe you could try `32dp`

Comment: Not working. Could you attach a screenshot of 6 tabs.

Comment: @Nitish, ok screenshots added

Comment: I owe you a big one Xcihnegn. I have doing one small mistake in my style. Above solution works great !! Thanks.

Comment: Applying this theme also fixed my [**other**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29347704/disable-actionbar-tab-indicator-programmatically/29443999#29443999) issue. I am a happy man :)

Comment: Really, that's great! Are you going to give me that bonus? ha ha ... kidding! You could answer your that `other` issue.

Comment: I think yes. Please post this style there as an answer. Your solution really deserves double bonus.

Comment: No I have got your bonus, please I think you should do that! Important to tell the solution for `other` issue

Answer (score 0):

As you're trying to achieve tabs on Actionbar which fits to width of device, one can use `PagerSlidingTabStrip` or `SlidingTabLayout` which gives you more flexibility in achieving tabs and its related Fragment with `ViewPager` which gives your Uix more efficient and user friendly touch.

Here I'm showing how to achieve it using `PagerSlidingTabStrip`

`PagerSlidingTabStrip.java` : Your Custom Tab View

```
public class PagerSlidingTabStrip extends HorizontalScrollView {

    public interface IconTabProvider {
        public int getPageIconResId(int position);
    }

    // @formatter:off
    private static final int[] ATTRS = new int[] { android.R.attr.textSize,
            android.R.attr.textColor };
    // @formatter:on

    private LinearLayout.LayoutParams defaultTabLayoutParams;
    private LinearLayout.LayoutParams expandedTabLayoutParams;

    private final PageListener pageListener = new PageListener();
    public OnPageChangeListener delegatePageListener;

    private LinearLayout tabsContainer;
    private ViewPager pager;

    private int tabCount;

    private int currentPosition = 0;
    private float currentPositionOffset = 0f;

    private Paint rectPaint;
    private Paint dividerPaint;

    private int currentPageSelected = 0; // Fix : ICON SELECTOR

    private int indicatorColor = 0xFF666666;
    private int underlineColor = 0x1A000000;
    private int dividerColor = 0x1A000000;

    private boolean shouldExpand = false;
    private boolean textAllCaps = true;

    private int scrollOffset = 52;
    private int indicatorHeight = 8;
    private int underlineHeight = 2;
    private int dividerPadding = 12;
    private int tabPadding = 24;
    private int dividerWidth = 1;

    private int tabTextSize = 12;
    private int tabTextColor = 0xFF666666;
    private Typeface tabTypeface = null;
    private int tabTypefaceStyle = Typeface.BOLD;

    private int lastScrollX = 0;

    private int tabBackgroundResId = R.drawable.background_tab;

    private Locale locale;

    public PagerSlidingTabStrip(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public PagerSlidingTabStrip(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public PagerSlidingTabStrip(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        setFillViewport(true);
        setWillNotDraw(false);

        tabsContainer = new LinearLayout(context);
        tabsContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        tabsContainer.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        addView(tabsContainer);

        DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

        scrollOffset = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, scrollOffset, dm);
        indicatorHeight = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, indicatorHeight, dm);
        underlineHeight = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, underlineHeight, dm);
        dividerPadding = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dividerPadding, dm);
        tabPadding = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, tabPadding, dm);
        dividerWidth = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dividerWidth, dm);
        tabTextSize = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, tabTextSize, dm);

        // get system attrs (android:textSize and android:textColor)

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, ATTRS);

        tabTextSize = a.getDimensionPixelSize(0, tabTextSize);
        tabTextColor = a.getColor(1, tabTextColor);

        a.recycle();

        // get custom attrs

        a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip);

        indicatorColor = a.getColor(
                R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsIndicatorColor,
                indicatorColor);
        underlineColor = a.getColor(
                R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsUnderlineColor,
                underlineColor);
        dividerColor = a
                .getColor(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsDividerColor,
                        dividerColor);
        indicatorHeight = a.getDimensionPixelSize(
                R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsIndicatorHeight,
                indicatorHeight);
        underlineHeight = a.getDimensionPixelSize(
                R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsUnderlineHeight,
                underlineHeight);
        dividerPadding = a.getDimensionPixelSize(
                R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsDividerPadding,
                dividerPadding);
        tabPadding = a.getDimensionPixelSize(
                R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsTabPaddingLeftRight,
                tabPadding);
        tabBackgroundResId = a.getResourceId(
                R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsTabBackground,
                tabBackgroundResId);
        shouldExpand = a
                .getBoolean(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsShouldExpand,
                        shouldExpand);
        scrollOffset = a
                .getDimensionPixelSize(
                        R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsScrollOffset,
                        scrollOffset);
        textAllCaps = a.getBoolean(
                R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsTextAllCaps, textAllCaps);

        a.recycle();

        rectPaint = new Paint();
        rectPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        rectPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);


        dividerPaint = new Paint();
        dividerPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        dividerPaint.setStrokeWidth(dividerWidth);

        defaultTabLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        expandedTabLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f);

        if (locale == null) {
            locale = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
        }
    }

    public void setViewPager(ViewPager pager) {
        this.pager = pager;

        if (pager.getAdapter() == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "ViewPager does not have adapter instance.");
        }

        pager.setOnPageChangeListener(pageListener);

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void setOnPageChangeListener(OnPageChangeListener listener) {
        this.delegatePageListener = listener;
    }

    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {

        tabsContainer.removeAllViews();

        tabCount = pager.getAdapter().getCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < tabCount; i++) {

            if (pager.getAdapter() instanceof IconTabProvider) {
                addIconTab(i,
                        ((IconTabProvider) pager.getAdapter())
                                .getPageIconResId(i));
            } else {
                addTextTab(i, pager.getAdapter().getPageTitle(i).toString());
            }

        }

        updateTabStyles();

        getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {

                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                            getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(
                                    this);
                        } else {
                            getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                                    this);
                        }

                        currentPosition = pager.getCurrentItem();
                        tabsContainer.getChildAt(currentPosition).setSelected(
                                true);// Fix : ICON SELECTOR
                        scrollToChild(currentPosition, 0);
                    }
                });

    }

    private void addTextTab(final int position, String title) {

        TextView tab = new TextView(getContext());
        tab.setText(title);
        tab.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tab.setSingleLine();

        addTab(position, tab);
    }

    private void addIconTab(final int position, int resId) {

        ImageButton tab = new ImageButton(getContext());
        tab.setImageResource(resId);

        addTab(position, tab);

    }

    private void addTab(final int position, View tab) {
        tab.setFocusable(true);
        tab.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pager.setCurrentItem(position);
            }
        });

        tab.setPadding(tabPadding, 0, tabPadding, 0);
        tabsContainer
                .addView(tab, position, shouldExpand ? expandedTabLayoutParams
                        : defaultTabLayoutParams);
    }

    private void updateTabStyles() {

        for (int i = 0; i < tabCount; i++) {

            View v = tabsContainer.getChildAt(i);

            v.setBackgroundResource(tabBackgroundResId);

            if (v instanceof TextView) {

                TextView tab = (TextView) v;
                tab.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, tabTextSize);
                tab.setTypeface(tabTypeface, tabTypefaceStyle);
                tab.setTextColor(tabTextColor);

                // setAllCaps() is only available from API 14, so the upper case
                // is made manually if we are on a
                // pre-ICS-build
                if (textAllCaps) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
                        tab.setAllCaps(true);
                    } else {
                        tab.setText(tab.getText().toString()
                                .toUpperCase(locale));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private void scrollToChild(int position, int offset) {

        if (tabCount == 0) {
            return;
        }

        int newScrollX = tabsContainer.getChildAt(position).getLeft() + offset;

        if (position > 0 || offset > 0) {
            newScrollX -= scrollOffset;
        }

        if (newScrollX != lastScrollX) {
            lastScrollX = newScrollX;
            scrollTo(newScrollX, 0);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (isInEditMode() || tabCount == 0) {
            return;
        }

        final int height = getHeight();

        // draw indicator line

        rectPaint.setColor(indicatorColor);

        // default: line below current tab
        View currentTab = tabsContainer.getChildAt(currentPosition);
        float lineLeft = currentTab.getLeft();
        float lineRight = currentTab.getRight();

        // if there is an offset, start interpolating left and right coordinates
        // between current and next tab
        if (currentPositionOffset > 0f && currentPosition < tabCount - 1) {

            View nextTab = tabsContainer.getChildAt(currentPosition + 1);
            final float nextTabLeft = nextTab.getLeft();
            final float nextTabRight = nextTab.getRight();

            lineLeft = (currentPositionOffset * nextTabLeft + (1f - currentPositionOffset)
                    * lineLeft);
            lineRight = (currentPositionOffset * nextTabRight + (1f - currentPositionOffset)
                    * lineRight);
        }

        //SU TU002
         canvas.drawRect(lineLeft, height - indicatorHeight, lineRight,height,
         rectPaint); 
//      canvas.drawRect(lineLeft, 0, lineRight, indicatorHeight, rectPaint); 
        // EU TU002

        // draw underline

        rectPaint.setColor(underlineColor);
        //SU TU002
         canvas.drawRect(0, height - underlineHeight,tabsContainer.getWidth(),
         height, rectPaint); 
//      canvas.drawRect(0, 0, tabsContainer.getWidth(), underlineHeight,
//              rectPaint); 
        // EU TU002

        // draw divider

        dividerPaint.setColor(dividerColor);
        for (int i = 0; i < tabCount - 1; i++) {
            View tab = tabsContainer.getChildAt(i);
            canvas.drawLine(tab.getRight(), dividerPadding, tab.getRight(),
                    height - dividerPadding, dividerPaint);
        }
    }

    private class PageListener implements OnPageChangeListener {

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
                int positionOffsetPixels) {

            currentPosition = position;
            currentPositionOffset = positionOffset;

            scrollToChild(position, (int) (positionOffset * tabsContainer
                    .getChildAt(position).getWidth()));

            invalidate();

            if (delegatePageListener != null) {
                delegatePageListener.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset,
                        positionOffsetPixels);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                scrollToChild(pager.getCurrentItem(), 0);
            }

            if (delegatePageListener != null) {
                delegatePageListener.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            /**
             * Fix : ICON SELECTOR
             */
            tabsContainer.getChildAt(currentPageSelected).setSelected(false);
            currentPageSelected = position;
            tabsContainer.getChildAt(position).setSelected(true);
            /**
             * Fix : ICON SELECTOR
             */

            if (delegatePageListener != null) {
                delegatePageListener.onPageSelected(position);
            }
        }

    }

    public void setIndicatorColor(int indicatorColor) {
        this.indicatorColor = indicatorColor;
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setIndicatorColorResource(int resId) {
        this.indicatorColor = getResources().getColor(resId);
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getIndicatorColor() {
        return this.indicatorColor;
    }

    public void setIndicatorHeight(int indicatorLineHeightPx) {
        this.indicatorHeight = indicatorLineHeightPx;
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getIndicatorHeight() {
        return indicatorHeight;
    }

    public void setUnderlineColor(int underlineColor) {
        this.underlineColor = underlineColor;
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setUnderlineColorResource(int resId) {
        this.underlineColor = getResources().getColor(resId);
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getUnderlineColor() {
        return underlineColor;
    }

    public void setDividerColor(int dividerColor) {
        this.dividerColor = dividerColor;
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setDividerColorResource(int resId) {
        this.dividerColor = getResources().getColor(resId);
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getDividerColor() {
        return dividerColor;
    }

    public void setUnderlineHeight(int underlineHeightPx) {
        this.underlineHeight = underlineHeightPx;
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getUnderlineHeight() {
        return underlineHeight;
    }

    public void setDividerPadding(int dividerPaddingPx) {
        this.dividerPadding = dividerPaddingPx;
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getDividerPadding() {
        return dividerPadding;
    }

    public void setScrollOffset(int scrollOffsetPx) {
        this.scrollOffset = scrollOffsetPx;
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getScrollOffset() {
        return scrollOffset;
    }

    public void setShouldExpand(boolean shouldExpand) {
        this.shouldExpand = shouldExpand;
        requestLayout();
    }

    public boolean getShouldExpand() {
        return shouldExpand;
    }

    public boolean isTextAllCaps() {
        return textAllCaps;
    }

    public void setAllCaps(boolean textAllCaps) {
        this.textAllCaps = textAllCaps;
    }

    public void setTextSize(int textSizePx) {
        this.tabTextSize = textSizePx;
        updateTabStyles();
    }

    public int getTextSize() {
        return tabTextSize;
    }

    public void setTextColor(int textColor) {
        this.tabTextColor = textColor;
        updateTabStyles();
    }

    public void setTextColorResource(int resId) {
        this.tabTextColor = getResources().getColor(resId);
        updateTabStyles();
    }

    public int getTextColor() {
        return tabTextColor;
    }

    public void setTypeface(Typeface typeface, int style) {
        this.tabTypeface = typeface;
        this.tabTypefaceStyle = style;
        updateTabStyles();
    }

    public void setTabBackground(int resId) {
        this.tabBackgroundResId = resId;
    }

    public int getTabBackground() {
        return tabBackgroundResId;
    }

    public void setTabPaddingLeftRight(int paddingPx) {
        this.tabPadding = paddingPx;
        updateTabStyles();
    }

    public int getTabPaddingLeftRight() {
        return tabPadding;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
        SavedState savedState = (SavedState) state;
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedState.getSuperState());
        currentPosition = savedState.currentPosition;
        requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
        Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();
        SavedState savedState = new SavedState(superState);
        savedState.currentPosition = currentPosition;
        return savedState;
    }

    static class SavedState extends BaseSavedState {
        int currentPosition;

        public SavedState(Parcelable superState) {
            super(superState);
        }

        private SavedState(Parcel in) {
            super(in);
            currentPosition = in.readInt();
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            super.writeToParcel(dest, flags);
            dest.writeInt(currentPosition);
        }

        public static final Parcelable.Creator<SavedState> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<SavedState>() {
            @Override
            public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new SavedState(in);
            }

            @Override
            public SavedState[] newArray(int size) {
                return new SavedState[size];
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Your Activity Layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <com.application.ui.view.PagerSlidingTabStrip
                android:id="@+id/pager_sliding_tab_strip"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dip"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@drawable/background_tabs"
                app:pstsIndicatorColor="@color/background_actionbar"
                app:pstsTabPaddingLeftRight="14dip" />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
        </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Your Activity :

```
public class MotherActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public static final String TAG = MotherActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private ViewPager mPager;
    private PagerSlidingTabStrip mPagerSlidingTabStrp;
    private ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener ViewPagerListener;
    private ActionBar mActionBar;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mother);
        initUi();
        setPagerSlidingTabStrip();
    }

private void initUi() {
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPagerSlidingTabStrp = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.pager_sliding_tab_strip);
    }

    private void setPagerSlidingTabStrip() {
        ViewPagerAdapter viewpageradapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);
        mPager.setAdapter(viewpageradapter);
        mPagerSlidingTabStrp.setShouldExpand(true);
        mPagerSlidingTabStrp.setViewPager(mPager);
    }
}
```

`ViewPagerAdapter` : which passes fragment on tab selection or swiping it. Pass on Fragment and drawables in here.

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements
        IconTabProvider {
    final int PAGE_COUNT = 5;
    private final int[] ICONS = { R.drawable.tab_icon_feed_home_selector,
            R.drawable.tab_icon_feed_friends_selector, R.drawable.tab_icon_feed_popular_selector,
            R.drawable.tab_icon_feed_report_selector,               R.drawable.tab_icon_feed_report_selector };

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int item) {
        switch (item) {
        case 0:
            FragmentAttendance fragmentAttendance = new FragmentAttendance();
            return fragmentAttendance;
        case 1:
            FragmentPremium fragmentPremium = new FragmentPremium();
            return fragmentPremium;
        case 2:
            FragmentLead fragmentLead = new FragmentLead();
            return fragmentLead;
        case 3:
            FragmentLead fragmentLead = new FragmentLead();
            return fragmentLead;
        case 4:
            FragmentLead fragmentLead = new FragmentLead();
            return fragmentLead;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPageIconResId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return ICONS[position];
    }
}
```

Comment: Firstly, I don't want to use ViewPager. I have a single webView and I am reloading it on tap of tabs. Secondly, could you point out where exactly are you controlling the width of tab ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code for changing the size of tab and making tabs fit within the screenwidth. Make sure your are using the Custom View

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
           getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
           int screenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;          
           final View tabView = actionBar.getTabAt(0).getCustomView();
           final View tabContainerView = (View) tabView.getParent();
           final int tabPadding = tabContainerView.getPaddingLeft() + tabContainerView.getPaddingRight();
           final int tabs = actionBar.getTabCount();
           for(int i=0 ; i < tabs ; i++) {
               View tab = actionBar.getTabAt(i).getCustomView();
          LinearLayout tabItemLayout = (LinearLayout) tab.findViewById(R.id.tabItemLayout);
          tabItemLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(screenWidth/tabs-tabPadding-1, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
          }
```

Comment: Which class are you importing / or using for LayoutParams?

Comment: ViewGroup.LayoutParams

Comment: Application crashed on using this.

Comment: It goes through the loop. But after that app crashes. I have put try catch but catch block is not called.